# Can we gather instance metadata within AWS::CloudFormation::Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

When configuring the AWS cloudwatch agent, you can include in the `{instance_id}` inside `awslogs.conf`

```
[/var/log/cfn-hup.log]
file = /var/log/cfn-hup.log
log_group_name = my-log-group
log_stream_name = {instance_id}/cfn-hup
```

Is there a way to do this within [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-files)?

Specifically I'm looking to add my Instance ID with the [files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-files) section

```yaml
Resources: 
  MyLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Metadata: 
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
        config:
          files: 
            /opt/someconfig.conf: 
              content: |
                INSTANCE_ID={instance_id}
              mode: "000644"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"
```

My work around was to append the `INSTANCE_ID` to my config file *after* the `cfn-init` command by running:

```sh
echo "INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)" >> /opt/someconfig.conf
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Had similar issue before. But I wasn't able to  find a "nice" way of doing this. So my workaround was using `sed` to replace `instance` or some other placeholders in the `Init` files.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the method Marcin pointed out in the comment

```yaml
Resources:
  MyLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          files:
            /opt/someconfig.conf:
              content: |
                INSTANCE_ID='INSTANCE_ID_PLACEHOLDER'
              mode: "000644"
              owner: "root"
    Properties:
      # removed for brevity
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe

          cfn-init -v \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --resource MyLaunchConfig \
            --region ${AWS::Region}

          INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

          sed -i "s/INSTANCE_ID_PLACEHOLDER/$INSTANCE_ID/g" /opt/someconfig.conf
```